# I'm getting an 'Unexpected token' error while executing a SQL query in DB2 using Squirrel client. Can someone help to resolve it?

Tags: sql, database, db2, unexpected-token

Below given is the query. This retrieved expected results when I executed it for the first time.

```
SELECT X.*,CONCAT(TVERTRAG.FIRMA,TVERTRAG.POLLFNR) AS POLICY_NUMBER FROM (
 SELECT VERTR#, AINHALT, REPLACE(LEFT(RIGHT(AINHALT, LENGTH(AINHALT) - LOCATE('##', AINHALT, 8)),
            LOCATE('##', CONCAT(RIGHT(AINHALT, LENGTH(AINHALT) 
                                                - LOCATE('##', AINHALT, 8))
                        ,'##')
                  )-1),'#','')
           AS RENEWAL_DATE, LEFT(AINHALT, LENGTH(AINHALT) - (LENGTH(AINHALT)-1)) AS COLLECTION_TYPE FROM TVERTRAG_GEN where ABEZ = 'IE_RENEW'  
  AND (AINHALT <> '' OR (AINHALT <> 'INCLUDED' OR AINHALT <> 'EXCLUDED')) 
  AND VERTR# IN (SELECT VERTR# FROM TVERTRAG where STADIUM = 3 AND ZUSTAND = 'A')) X, TVERTRAG  
 WHERE X.VERTR# = TVERTRAG.VERTR# 
 AND DATE(X.RENEWAL_DATE) = DATE('2023-10-01')
```

Afterwards, it started throwing the error given below

```
An unexpected token "," was found following "OM (
 SELECT VERTR#".  Expected tokens may include:  "<join_type_without_spec> JOIN <join_operand>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.66.46 SQL Code: -104, SQL State: 42601
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me resolve it.

Comment: Try double-quoting identifiers that have non-alphanumeric characters, e.g. " VERTR#"  , matching the upper/lowercase characters exactly per column in the database.

Comment: Please, edit your question with the corresponding `CREATE TABLE TVERTRAG_GEN ...` and `CREATE TABLE TVERTRAG ...` statements to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mao - It didn't work even after double-quoting.

Comment: Did you copy this query from an application like Teams? It may have added some [nbsp characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Comment: @Keraion - I copied it from confluence.

Comment: @keraion - I tried copying the query to Notepad first and from there to the Squirrel client and it worked. Many thanks